# How to use "async" or "await" inside for-loop in my code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to develop a tool to scrap and post data from/to websites using "puppeteer",I wrote two modules one to read the URLS from JSON file and has the for-loop which include the function from the other module which visit the website and scrap the data.

When I built the functions, and run the code, for the first time my PC hang, and couldn't identify the issue, until I came across **post** explaining about **"async"** and **"await"** in NodeJS,I tried to understand how to apply it to my code, but I couldn't.

So I'm trying exactly to go through the loop to visit the website, then scrap data, after I finish from the first element,  it should go to the next element in the loop rather than execute all elements in one time which make the PC hang.

**getUrlsAndVisitWebsite.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs');
var visitWebsite= require('/home/projtect1/visitWebsite.js');

async function getUrlsAndVisitWebsite(){
    
  fs.readFile("/home/project1/urls.json", "utf8", (err, jsonString) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("File read failed:", err);
      return;
      }

  var jsonOBj= JSON.parse(jsonString);
  
  for  (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    var postPath = JSON.parse(jsonOBj[i]).url;
 
    // here I'm using puppeteer to visit websites and scrab data
    visitWebsite(postPath)
    }
  });
}

getUrlsAndVisitWebsite()
```

**visitWebsite.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
var fs = require('fs');

async function visitWebsite(postPath){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
        headless: false,
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
        
     })

    
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setViewport({ width: 0, height: 0});

    //Loading Cookie from file
    const cookiesString = await fs.readFileSync('./cookies.json');
    
    const Writecookies = JSON.parse(cookiesString);
    await page.setCookie(...Writecookies);

    // GO to the target URL for post 
    console.log(postPath)
    await page.goto(postPath)
    //Wait for the selector that list the elements
    await page.waitForSelector('#gridPostListing');

}

module.exports=visitWebsite;
```

Comment: since `getUrlsAndVisitWebsite` is `async` you can simply use `await visitWebsite(postPath)`

Comment: Use for of instead of for that will work

Comment: The first thing you should probably avoid is starting a new browser instance for every URL. Rewrite your code so that it re-uses the `browser`  object and only opens a new page per URL.

Answer (score 0):

Your visitWebsite function is async, you need to await it in getUrlsAndVisitWebsite. As it is now, it only returns a promise, hence it hangs.

Just add await before your visitWebsite call.

Comment: Doesn't work, tried it before.

Comment: Did you also add await before calling getUrlsAndVisitWebsite() ?

Comment: Yes I did, doesn't work.